# asymptotic proportionality

Tags: notation, asymptotics

Is there a well established notation for asymptotic proportionality by a non-zero and non-unitary constant (for null contant we have little-oh, for unitary constant of asymptotic proportionality we have $\sim$)? Is for example the usual proportionality symbol $\propto$ extended to such use?

Answer (score 0):

I think, if I understood correctly, that $\Theta$ is what you're looking for?

$$f = \Theta(g) \leftrightarrow \exists M>0, (C_1, C_2) \in \mathbb{R}; \forall x>M, C_1<\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}<C_2$$

Comment: Unfortunately this is a bit more general than what I intended, this notation expresses only a bound for the asymptotic proportionality constant.

Comment: Then yes, $\propto$ is what you need: $f\propto g \leftrightarrow  \exists a, f=ag$

Comment: But the problem is exactly the definition of $\propto$ as a relationship: standard definition and use requires the constant a you use in your definition to work for every x (implicitly assumed in your definition by minimal notation). What I am asking is if it is standard use in research to use $\propto$ when the proportionality may hold only in the limit (therefore including cases in which it does no hold for any finite x).

Comment: Oh, then I'm afraid I'm not aware of any specific notation... You'd have to spell it out as $\frac{f}{g} \rightarrow a$ I guess